# useEffect multiple dependencies

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

Before question please check code below...

```
useEffect(() => {
  //sending request to database
  // a, b, c => those can be changed after response
}, [a, b, c])
```

in this component I have cases when if one of dependencies are changed may other will too.
so my goal is that if one of them is updated I want to ignore others.
is this even possible or I have to find other way

Comment: Use separate hooks for each one?

Comment: I had this exact specific question; no further clarification needed; both the question and the answer posted by user Asad are very straightforward and easy to understand, which enabled me to solve my own exact same issue. It's very easy to tell exactly what is being asked.

Answer (score 1):

use separate hooks for every state.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // only a's updated value will be available within this hook. every change in b , c will not update this hook clouser.
}, [a])
```

Comment: This straightforward answer should be the accepted answer to the very straightforward question.